# Regular expression - Unknown modifier '(' in

Tags: php

I had this regular expression:

```
preg_match("|[\|()<>%*+=]|(=)+(!)|[-]{2}|", $status, $array);
```

that generates this warning

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '(' in...
```

I know that is a problem of `\` but I don't know where to put them.

Comment: Read [PCRE regex syntax: Delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `|` as the delimiter for the pattern, so the second `|` ends the pattern and the `(` is interpreted as a modifier. Do one of these, depending on if you need the `|` at the beginning and end:

```
preg_match("/|[\|()<>%*+=]|(=)+(!)|[-]{2}|/", $status, $array);
preg_match("/[\|()<>%*+=]|(=)+(!)|[-]{2}/", $status, $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The is some problems... Let see:

Yours:

```
  "|[\|()<>%*+=]|(=)+(!)|[-]{2}|"
   ^ first problem not needed as is an OR and there is nothing before it
       ^ you have to scape the parentesis all of it
            ^ you have to scape the asterisk
                               ^unecessary there is nothing after
```

So the result would be:

```
  "/[\|\(\)<>%\*+=]|(=)+(!)|[-]{2}/"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I used your regular expression ;)